# Apt-get update encounters errors with bad GPG keys

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates

i have errors withing sudo apt-get update

```
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
```

i try this commands:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 40976EAF437D05B5
```

and this

```
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get update
```

but i still have the same problem

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but try this thread, may be a stale key fixed by getting rid of cached files. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=802156